# I have a question regarding the pricing of Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Which option is more cost-effective in Firestore: updating a document with 15 NUMBER fields or updating five documents with one NUMBER field each?

I am optimizing the document structure in terms of pricing and researching the pricing aspect of Firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of fields changed in a document update operation is irrelevant for billing.  A single document update operation always costs the same. Updating 5 documents always costs 5 times more than a single document update operation.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations):

> Charges for writes and deletes are straightforward. For writes, each set or update operation counts as a single write.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a difference between retrieving one snapshot of the NUMBER field from five documents and retrieving 15 NUMBER fields from one document?

Comment: The documentation I linked to also discusses charges for reads. Number of fields are irrelevant.